# how to make a context free grammar with no left recursion to include a left recursion (without changing the language of the grammar)?

Tags: recursion, context-free-grammar, left-recursion

assume we have a context free grammar , if it is in LL[1] , then it has only right Associative !
but let's say i want to make this context free grammar have a left Associative  , then it will not stay in LL[1] , (which is okay)
i figured that in order to make a context free grammar have a left Associative i should make it have left recursion .
is there is a way to include left recursion to a context free grammar without changing the language of the grammar ?
for example if we have this context free grammar :

```
1: S -> sum ( ELIST )
2: ELIST -> E , ELIST
3: ELIST -> E
4: E -> num
5: E -> id
6: E -> S
```

how to make this include a left recursion so the operator "," will now be left Associative ?

Comment: Associativity is related to the meaning (semantics) of a language, while grammars are related to the syntax.  So they are really independent.

Comment: if a context free grammar is in LL[1] , then it support only right Associativity  ! i checked it ! what i mean with right Associativity  , is that  for every series of rules applied i only get a tree that is going to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your second production to:

2: ELIST -> ELIST , E

This does not change the language, only the way the language is parsed.

This modification should work with any expression grammar written in cascading precedence style. But it is not a transformation which can be applied to any grammar whatsoever.